# Stop background audio on android app

Tags: android, audio

im working on simple audio application but i have a major problem because audio wont stop when user press home button or move app to background

i tried to use **onPause()** but it not work for me please can anyone help ?

```
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

final MediaPlayer angry = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.angry);

 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(angry.isPlaying()) {

                    angry.pause();
                    button1.setText("Play");

                } else {

                    angry.start();
                    angry.setLooping(true);
                    button1.setText("Pause");

                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pausing MediaPlayer instance in `onPause()` method.
But from your code, your `final MediaPlayer angry` is only exist in `onCreate()` method as local object variable. To fix your problem, you need to move out your `angry` object  from `onCreate()` method, so you can access it from `onPause()` method.
Here's example:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
MediaPlayer angry; //Now it is here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     angry = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.angry);
```

And you should pause it in `onPause()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause ()
{
  if (angry != null)
  {
    angry.pause();
    angry.stop();
  }
  super.onPause();
}
```